# jenkinsfile error out due to git safe.directory requirement

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Team,
any hint how can I fix this as I even tried the suggestion as per error log but avails no help.

basically, I need to resolve this `git config --global --add safe.directory /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-pipeline`

```
16:50:00  + git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 66a80a67670f9cdfe73e637882e19693bfb4
16:50:00  + grep -v OWNERS
16:50:00  + grep -v gitignore
16:50:00  fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-pipeline'
16:50:00  To add an exception for this directory, call:
16:50:00  
16:50:00    git config --global --add safe.directory /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-pipeline
```

i did below but no luck

```
def gitCheckout(String gitRepository, String gitRefSpec, String jenkinsCredentialId=DEFAULT_JENKINS_GIT_CREDENTIALS){
        checkoutInfo = checkout([
          $class: 'GitSCM',
          branches: [[name: 'FETCH_HEAD']],
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
          extensions: [
            [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],
            [$class: 'CloneOption', shallow: true, noTags: true, depth: 2, honorRefspec: true]
          ],
          submoduleCfg: [],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[
            credentialsId: jenkinsCredentialId,
            name: '',
            refspec: gitRefSpec,
            url: gitRepository]]
        ])
        return checkoutInfo.GIT_COMMIT
}
```

```
stages
{
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            container('main') {
            script {
                git config --global --add safe.directory "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-pipeline"
                workspace = pwd()

                if (params.GERRIT_BRANCH != "main"){
                echo "INFO: Changes will be processed from git hash"
                }
                git_revision = gitCheckout(params.GERRIT_REPO, params.GERRIT_BRANCH)
                echo "GitRevision: ${git_revision}"

                if (params.GERRIT_BRANCH != "main" && ! params.TF_TEMPLATE_PATH){
                    echo "INFO: Changes will be processed from git hash"
                    changed_files = sh(script: "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${git_revision} |grep -v 'OWNERS' |grep -v 'gitignore'", returnStdout: true).split("\n")
                    echo "Changed Files: ${changed_files}"
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `AFTER CHECKOUT/after actual files from git is on filesystem`

`git config --global --add safe.directory "*"`

this error occurs because you use checkout of directory with one user (you haven't provide full pipeline) and then trying to use files with another user

```
container('first') {
git checkout
}

container('second') {
 git add . or anything else 
}
```

`first` container in image has user "BOB" in dockerfile

`second` container in image has user "NICK" in dockerfile

git fixed security so you have to do `git config --global --add safe.directory "$(pwd)"` when trying to do git actions with files which current user dont own

more info [here](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9)